# Python - Calling python function from another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to call a DB connection from another python script. I keep getting an error NameError: name

```
'db_cur'
```

is not defined. Given below is the code I am using:

file1.py

```
import psycopg2
def db_login():
    global dwh_connection
    global dwh_cur
    try:
        dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(db_details)
        db_cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
    except:
        print("Conn failed")
    print('Connection Success')
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import db_login

def rep1():
    db_cur.execute("""SQL statement""")
    dwh_connection.commit()
    dwh_connection.close()
    print('Task Completed')
```

This throws an error

```
NameError: name 'db_cur' is not defined
```

Could anyone help me figure where I am going wrong in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`db_cur` has local scope in `db_login`. This means that it cannot be accessed outside `db_login`. A better way of doing this would be to return the object and use the returned object in script 2.

For example, file1.py:

```
import psycopg2

def db_login():
    global dwh_connection
    global dwh_cur
    try:
        dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(db_details)
        db_cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
        return db_cur 
    except:
        print("Conn failed")
        return None
    print('Connection Success')
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import db_login

def rep1():
    db_cur = db_login()
    if db_cur is not None:
        db_cur.execute("""SQL statement""")
        dwh_connection.commit()
        dwh_connection.close()

    print('Task Completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, "global" really means "module-level global", not "application global", so `dwh_connection` and `dwh_cur` won't be automagically available in `file2`.

This being said, relying globals here is a bad idea - you `db_login()` function should *return* the connection instead of setting a global (or in addition to setting a module level global if you want to avoid opening multiple connections).

Also, you should not create a cursor here at all - cursors are not reentrant and should be created afresh each time you need one (creating a cursor is very cheap).

And finally, your exception handler in `db_login()` is worse than useless, it's just plain harmful - instead of a detailed error message (and traceback) explaining as exactly as possible what went wrong (so you have a chance to dbug the problem), you just have a totaly useless "conn failed" message.

To make a long story short, the "correct" equivalent version of your function is:

```
def db_login():
    return psycopg2.connect(db_details)
```

Also note that in your `file2.py` module you import `db_login` but never call it:

```
from file1 import db_login

def foo():
    db = db_login()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        # do something with the cursor
    finally:
       # make sure you close the connection
       db.close()
```